# How to fire a "change" event when the user releases the range slider, even if the value hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom-events

```js
var control = $('#control');

var zone = 2;
const SNAP_TARGET = 1;
const SNAP_DISTANCE = 0.1;
const LEEWAY = 0.01;

function getSliderInfo() {
  const sliderVal = parseFloat(control.val());
  return [sliderVal, sliderVal - SNAP_TARGET];
}

control.on('input', function () {
  const [position, difference] = getSliderInfo();
  let offset = -difference;
  if (difference < 0 && zone === 3) {
    if (difference <= -SNAP_DISTANCE) {
      zone = 1;
    }
  }
  else if (difference > 0 && zone === 1) {
    if (difference >= SNAP_DISTANCE) {
      zone = 3;
    }
  }
  else {
    offset = 0;
    if (zone === 2) {
      if (Math.abs(difference) > LEEWAY) {
        zone = difference < 0 ? 1 : 3;
      }
      else {
        control.val(1);
      }
    }
  }
  control.val(position + offset);
});

control.on('change', function () {
  const difference = getSliderInfo()[1];
  if (Math.abs(difference) <= LEEWAY) {
    control.val(1);
    zone = 2;
  }
  console.log('change event occured');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='control' type='range' min='0' max='2' value='1' step='any'>
```

I made a slider with the extra feature of allowing the user to easily set it to the exact center. Try it and see how it stops it right in the middle, but you can slide it anywhere if you continue dragging it past the stop zone or drag it the other way.

If the user drags the slider knob to the midpoint and releases their mouse, the "stickiness" should be removed so it doesn't start out "stuck" when they begin to drag it again.

The problem is, if the user slides it away from the midpoint where it started and then slides it back to the midpoint, the `change` event won't fire because the final value didn't actually change.

I tried using `mouseup`/`pointerup` instead of `change` but there's a case where it doesn't work. You can click and hold down on the slider knob, then move your cursor vertically outside the slider's area, and release the mouse. The `mouseup`/`pointerup` event doesn't fire since you released the button when your cursor was outside of the input.

How to fire a `change` event when the user releases the range slider, even if the value hasn't changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Set a variable to `true` in `mousedown` of `control` and check it in `mouseup` event of `document`

```js
var control = $('#control');
let mousedown = false;
var zone = 2;
const SNAP_TARGET = 1;
const SNAP_DISTANCE = 0.1;
const LEEWAY = 0.01;

function getSliderInfo() {
  const sliderVal = parseFloat(control.val());
  return [sliderVal, sliderVal - SNAP_TARGET];
}
//control.on('click',function(){console.log("changed")})
control.on('input', function () {
  const [position, difference] = getSliderInfo();
  let offset = -difference;
  if (difference < 0 && zone === 3) {
    if (difference <= -SNAP_DISTANCE) {
      zone = 1;
    }
  }
  else if (difference > 0 && zone === 1) {
    if (difference >= SNAP_DISTANCE) {
      zone = 3;
    }
  }
  else {
    offset = 0;
    if (zone === 2) {
      if (Math.abs(difference) > LEEWAY) {
        zone = difference < 0 ? 1 : 3;
      }
      else {
        control.val(1);
      }
    }
  }
  control.val(position + offset);
});
$(document).on('mouseup',function(){
  if(mousedown){
     change();
     mousedown = false;
  }
})

control.on('mousedown',() => mousedown = true);
function change() {
  const difference = getSliderInfo()[1];
  if (Math.abs(difference) <= LEEWAY) {
    control.val(1);
    zone = 2;
  }
  console.log('change event occured');
}
control.on('change', change);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='control' type='range' min='0' max='2' value='1' step='any'>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace change by click :-

```js
var control = $('#control');

var zone = 2;
const SNAP_TARGET = 1;
const SNAP_DISTANCE = 0.1;
const LEEWAY = 0.01;

function getSliderInfo() {
  const sliderVal = parseFloat(control.val());
  return [sliderVal, sliderVal - SNAP_TARGET];
}

control.on('input', function () {
  const [position, difference] = getSliderInfo();
  let offset = -difference;
  if (difference < 0 && zone === 3) {
    if (difference <= -SNAP_DISTANCE) {
      zone = 1;
    }
  }
  else if (difference > 0 && zone === 1) {
    if (difference >= SNAP_DISTANCE) {
      zone = 3;
    }
  }
  else {
    offset = 0;
    if (zone === 2) {
      if (Math.abs(difference) > LEEWAY) {
        zone = difference < 0 ? 1 : 3;
      }
      else {
        control.val(1);
      }
    }
  }
  control.val(position + offset);
});

control.on('mouseup', function () {
  const difference = getSliderInfo()[1];
  if (Math.abs(difference) <= LEEWAY) {
    control.val(1);
    zone = 2;
  }
  console.log('change event occured');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='control' type='range' min='0' max='2' value='1' step='any'>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you drag your cursor down and release the mouse outside of the range input.

Comment: OP is correct. If you drag the slider to the end, release it, then click the slider again, drag your mouse off of it without the slider moving and then release it, it won't fire the click or change event.

Comment: Issue fixed. I believe your solution is better than the accepted answer. This answer only fires a single event when the slider is interacted with and it doesn't create a `mouseup` listener on the entire document.